# How to use php 5.5 password api with Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-auth, php-password-hash

Until now I have stored all passwords in plain text because the site is not live and I decided to wait for the new [password api](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php).

I have this code working for passwords in plain text:

```
<?php
$dbAdapter = Zend_Db_Table::getDefaultAdapter();
$authAdapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable($dbAdapter);

$authAdapter->setTableName('account')
    ->setIdentityColumn('account_id')
    ->setCredentialColumn('account_password');

// Get our authentication adapter and check credentials
$adapter = $authAdapter;
$adapter->setIdentity($values['account_id']);
$adapter->setCredential($values['password']);

$auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);
if ($result->isValid()) {
    $user = $adapter->getResultRowObject();
    $auth->getStorage()->write($user);
    return true;
}
return false;
```

According to [docs](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.auth.introduction.html) I should implement my own adapter and probably just change to make use of password_verify().

I'm missing the big picture here to how everything is working together.

My question is:

1. Witch object should I modify? `$authAdaper` or `$auth`

Any high level (or low level :D) example code would be appreciated.

All best
Adam

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to modify the way in which your authentication operates by adding the `password_hash` encryption then 
you will need to do so within `PHP`.

As you still wish to use database authentication I think recreating this as a new adapter would be overkill. You **could** however, extend the current database adapter, such as:

```
class My_Auth_Adapter_DbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable
{
  public function setCredential($credential)
  {
    $this->_credential = password_hash($credential);
    return $this;
  }
}
```

This means that any password provided to the adapter will always be encrypted with the `password_hash` function.

This could however be acomplished outside the adapter by hashing the password prior to the call to `setCredential`.

```
$options  = array('salt' => $config->passwordSalt);
$hashPassword = password_hash($plainTextPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options);
$adpater->setCredential($hashPassword);
```

This method will allow you to modify the optional parameters before passing to the adapter.

Lastly, it is worth mentioning that the `setCredentialTreatment` method is normally used to provided password encryption, which is performed within the SQL statement (meaning you will need to use the MySQL commands and not `password_hash`).

```
$authAdapter->setTableName('user')
      ->setIdentityColumn('email')
      ->setCredentialColumn('password')
      ->setCredentialTreatment(sprintf("MD5(CONCAT(?,'%s'))", $config->passwordSalt));
```

Comment: $adpater->setCredential($hashPassword); by doing this way I need to store the salt separately in db?

Comment: Don't I need to make use of password_verify() anywhere??

Comment: If you want to use one salt for all passwords then you can define it in your `application.ini`. `$config->passwordSalt` is just a string, `$config` being a `Zend_Config` instance.

Comment: You wont need to use `password_verify` as the password matching will be done in the SQL statement. You will however **need** to hash all your passwords in the database, using the same salt and hash algorithm you use when authenticating.

Comment: so none of your solutions will work if I don't want to make a separate salt? According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right#comment21070137_14992543) you should let the new password api take care of the salt.

Comment: Yes, option 1 or option 2 both work. If You create the hashed password using `password_hash` it will return a hash string...regardless of what salt you have used (internal or one you provide). This is then what the adapter will compare against in the database. Providing the password in the database are already hashed it is a simple comparision of hash password to hashed password. i.e. `WHERE password = '$hashedPassword`

Comment: option 2 is now tested and now working but I'm concerned that using the same salt for all passwords and salt in clear text in my config file could open up for vulnerabilities.

Comment: You **do need** to use  ̀password_verify()` as SQL cannot compare hashes created by `password_hash()` as 2 hashes for the same password are not always equals (at least not with BCRYPT or ARGON2).

Answer (score 0):

Hashes created by `password_hash()` needs to be compared via  ̀password_verify()` because 2 hashes for the same password are not always equals (at least not with BCRYPT or ARGON2).

```
<?php
$pass = 'foo';
var_dump(password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT) === password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT));
// bool(false)
var_dump(password_verify($pass, password_hash($pass, PASSWORD_BCRYPT)));
// bool(true)
```

Someone ([s7anley](https://gist.github.com/s7anley)) did a [`Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable` extension that uses password_verify()](https://gist.github.com/s7anley/b497c7cd05dec10ee75f), here it is (for reference):

```
<?php

class Base_Auth_Adapter_BcryptDbTable extends Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _authenticateCreateSelect()
    {
        $dbSelect = clone $this->getDbSelect();
        $dbSelect->from($this->_tableName)
            ->where($this->_zendDb->quoteIdentifier($this->_identityColumn, true) . ' = ?', $this->_identity);

        return $dbSelect;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function _authenticateValidateResult($resultIdentity)
    {
        $passwordCheck = password_verify($this->_credential, $resultIdentity[$this->_credentialColumn]);

        if (!$passwordCheck) {
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['code'] = Zend_Auth_Result::FAILURE_CREDENTIAL_INVALID;
            $this->_authenticateResultInfo['messages'][] = 'Supplied credential is invalid.';
            return $this->_authenticateCreateAuthResult();
        }

        $this->_resultRow = $resultIdentity;

        $this->_authenticateResultInfo['code'] = Zend_Auth_Result::SUCCESS;
        $this->_authenticateResultInfo['messages'][] =  'Authentication successful.';
        return $this->_authenticateCreateAuthResult();
    }
}
```

The class name says "Bcrypt" but it will work just fine with any algorithm supported by `password_hash()`.

You can use it like that:

```
$authAdapter = new Base_Auth_Adapter_BcryptDbTable($databaseAdapter, 'users', 'login', 'password');
$authAdapter
    ->setIdentity('my_username')
    ->setCredential('my_password') // "clear" password
    // ->setCredentialTreatment(null) // Can't set any treatment on password (would be ignored)
;
// For any additional filtering of returned rows, use getDbSelect()
$authAdapter->getDbSelect()->where('active = "TRUE"');
```