# How to verify password against database?

Tags: php, hash

I went through many articles related to this topic, such as this:

[Using PHP 5.5's password_hash and password_verify function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right)

Yet, I'm unsure if I'm hashing and salting the correct way or over doing it!

I want to use my own salt and then hash. Both salt and hashed password stored in the database in two different fields.

This is how I hash the password before storing into database

```
$cost = 10;
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$salt = sprintf("$2a$%02d$", $cost) . $salt;

//shall I remove this line and replace below PASSWORD_DEFAULT  with PASSWORD_BCRYPT instead?
$password = crypt($data['password'], $salt);

$hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Given that, I'm trying to verify the password as below: Somehow I feel that I'm complicating the process.

```
$salt=$row['salt'];//taken from db
$hashAndSalt=$row['hashpword'];//taken from db
$password="pwtester";//user keyed in password

$newpassword = crypt($password, $salt);
$newhash = password_hash($newpassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


if (password_verify($password, $newhash)) {
   echo"verified";
}
else
{
    echo"Not verified"; 
}
```

EDITED:

Now I store like this:

```
$cost = 10;
$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');
$options = array('cost' => $cost,'salt' => $salt);
$hash = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT,$options);
```

But verification confusing:

```
$email = "test55@gmail.com";
$uid= '555ca83664caf';
$sql = "SELECT *FROM authsessions WHERE email =:myemail AND useruuid =:uid";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':myemail', $email);
$statement->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
$statement->execute();
while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
    echo "salt ".$row['salt']."<br/><br/>";
    echo "hashpassword ".$row['hashpword'];
}

$salt=$row['salt'];
$hashAndSalt=$row['hashpword'];
$password="test55";

$newhash = password_hash($password+$salt, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


if (password_verify($newhash, $hashAndSalt)) {
   echo"verified";
}
else
{
    echo"Not verified"; 
}
```

It echoes "Not Verified"

Comment: @user3633383, what value? Hmm I'm getting the salt string and hashed password, but when I verify it says not verified

Comment: Ok, I have never used these functions before. What seems to be hapening is that you are hashing the password and then using it to verify if it is a valid password. The `password_verify()` takes the original password unhashed.

Answer (score 6):

The function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is just a wrapper, internally it generates a cryptographically safe salt and then calls the `crypt()` function to calculate the BCrypt hash.

So there is no reason to do the same steps yourself (do not call crypt() and do not generate a salt). Generating your own salt is not recommended, because you cannot do it better than the password_hash function does. Also there is no reason to store the salt in a separate db column, it is already part of the resulting hash-value.

```
// Hash a new password for storing in the database.
// The function automatically generates a cryptographically safe salt.
$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

// Check if the hash of the entered login password, matches the stored hash.
// The salt and the cost factor will be extracted from $existingHashFromDb.
$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($password, $existingHashFromDb);
```

Answer (score 5):

This will verify correctly, as it should.

```
//on creating an account, a user enters a password!
$password="pwtester";//user keyed in password

$newhash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
//#newhash now has the only value that you need to store in the db
//you do not need any more than this value, that you retrieve when you 
//want to verify your password!

//this part is only done to verify passwords!
if (password_verify($password, $newhash)) {
    echo"verified";
}
else
{
    echo"Not verified"; 
}
```

So provided you have stored the hash in the db

```
$newhash=$row['hashpword'];//taken from db
$password="pwtester";//user keyed in password

if (password_verify($password, $newhash)) {
    echo"verified";
}
else
{
    echo"Not verified"; 
}
```

Should work!

Comment: PLease take a look at my edited code: I'm unsure how to verify against  my salt and then hash..For extra security I need manual salting included

Answer (score 1):

Password storage:

```
$cost = 10;

$salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

$options = array('cost' => $cost,'salt' => $salt); 

$hash = password_hash($data['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT,$options);
```

password verify:

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$email = "test55@gmail.com";
$uid= '555cb0a63f08d';
$sql = "SELECT *FROM authsessions WHERE  useruuid =:uid";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->bindValue(':uid', $uid);
$statement->execute();
while( $row = $statement->fetch()) {
echo "salt ".$salt=$row['salt']."<br/><br/>";
echo "hashpassword ".$hashAndSalt=$row['hashpword'];
echo"<br/>";
}

$password="nony";



//$newhash = password_hash($password+$salt, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


if (password_verify($password, $hashAndSalt)) {
   echo"verified";
}
else
{
echo"Not verified"; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You hash the password 2 times.
Leave the crypt function and you should be ok.

Just take a look at the PHP documentation regarding to password_verify and password_hash.

Just save the password with password_hash(). that should store the hash in the DB.

And to verify, you just compare the hash with the user input with password_verify. Password_verify will do the rest for you :)