# Modern php hashing algorithm

Tags: php, algorithm, security, hash

I'm developing a new system and I wondered if my oldschool phpass is still the best option for hashing in php?

I'm looking for the best security, and I heard that blowfish is outdated. DES is old.

So what will you guys recommend for a new php system? I need something that is future-proof as replacing the algorithm after the release is a pain.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Modern PHP uses the built-in password_hash()/password_verify() functions; when it doesn't even matter if the algorithm is changed by future versions of PHP

Comment: @MarkBaker beat me to it for the second time today. This has to stop :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP 5.5 has a built in password_hash() and password_verify() function and it is very powerful.

[The docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)

[How to on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right)

Make sure your php version is 5.5 or above before you try to implement it.

Comment: But note that you can use the [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat) from PHP >= 5.3.7

Comment: Okay. tried that password_hash function and it seems to work great. now trying to verify it. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You can look at [Mhash](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mhash.php) php extention, mhash() and SHA-512 as algorythm

Comment: From that manual page: "Note: This extension is obsoleted by Hash." That's not exactly modern.