# Php login system with session

Tags: php, forms, session, authentication

I'm making a login form with session but. i've got an issue with it.

The problem is. When i press on the submit button i got send to the "login.php" instead of "office.php". Also the "error" variable is empty. so i dont know what the problem is.

**Index.php**

```
<?php
include('login.php'); // Includes Login Script

if(isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
header("location: office.php");
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Login Form in PHP with Session</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <h1>PHP Login Session Example</h1>
      <div id="login">
        <h2>Login Form</h2>
        <form method="post" action="login.php">
          <input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="1">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default">
          </div>
        </form>
        <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
  session_start(); // Starting Session
  $error=''; // Variable To Store Error Message
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
      $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    else {
    // Define $username and $password
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
    // To protect MySQL injection for Security purpose
    $username = stripslashes($username);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $username = mysql_real_escape_string($username);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($password);
    // Selecting Database
    $db = mysql_select_db("businesslife", $connection);
    // SQL query to fetch information of registerd users and finds user match.
    $query = mysql_query("select * from users where Use_Pass='$password' AND Use_Name='$username'");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
    if ($rows == 1) {
      $_SESSION['login_user']=$username; // Initializing Session
      header("location: office.php"); // Redirecting To Other Page
    } 
    else {
      $error = "Username or Password is invalid";
    }
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
  }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span><?php echo $error; ?></span>
    </body>
</html>
```

**office.php**

```
<?php
  include('session.php');
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Your Home Page</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="profile">
      <b id="welcome">Welcome : <i><?php echo $login_session; ?></i></b>
      <b id="logout"><a href="logout.php">Log Out</a></b>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**session.php**

```
<?php
  // Establishing Connection with Server by passing server_name, user_id and password as a parameter
  $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");

  // Selecting Database
  $db = mysql_select_db("businesslife", $connection);
  session_start();// Starting Session

  // Storing Session
  $user_check=$_SESSION['login_user'];

  // SQL Query To Fetch Complete Information Of User
  $ses_sql=mysql_query("select username from login where username='$user_check'", $connection);
  $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ses_sql);
  $login_session =$row['username'];

  if(!isset($login_session)){
    mysql_close($connection); // Closing Connection
    header('Location: index.php'); // Redirecting To Home Page
  }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

I would realy appreciate your help

Comment: You don't have to use `stripslashes` when using `mysql_real_escape_string`. You should, however, stop using `mysql_` functions as [they are removed in PHP 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). Also, storing passwords as plain text is a bad idea. [Consider password_hash instead](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right)

Comment: check for errors. This will never happen `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}`

Comment: There is no element with name submit...

Comment: Please refactor your MYSQL to either mysqli or PDO mysql.. 
Just using one of those 2 default binding / escaping of inputs will give you a lot more security

Comment: I'm just curious who's up voting this question?

Comment: I forgot to give my submit button a name :p thanks for help