# php password_hash changing when refresh

Tags: php, php-password-hash

I am trying to build a form with a password input.
I am trying to hash the password via `php password_hash` and save it in the DB.
And when the users logs in, i will hash his input and check if its the same like in the DB.

The Problem is that when I use password_hash it gives me a random output everytime I refresh. The input is still the same. That makes it impossible for the user to log in because the outputhash will never match whats in the DB.

I am testing it like that:

```
$pw = "hello";
echo password_hash ($pw, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

the first echo = $2y$10$7GwPLFNIhybl6tcyuYsH..Dtgfn2hF7RUDwZ99o7BkL6eza4Dsope;
echo again = $2y$10$7tvaZHupw8Ik8Id/ImHCHekpp/Deg4E.XkG82zaVYx262Exv3zMde;
```

Am I doing smt wrong? plz help

Comment: you use `password_verify` to match...

Comment: and so it should. RTM if you want to keep a constant hash. http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using PHP 5.5's \`password\_hash()\` and verify function, am I doing it right?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. you are doing something wrong.

The `hash` **is** expected to change on every request. That's the purpose.

What you need to be doing is verfiying the password against that hash.

```
if(password_verify($password, $hash)){
    //correct
}
```

Don't try to compare the hash on every page load.

Comment: How can i compare the password with the hash if the hash is changing everytime i load the page?

Comment: @hatemjapo The `hash` should be stored somewhere `securely`. Such as a database, or a file. For testing purposes, you can store it in `$_SESSION['hash'] = $hash` and then check for it on page load `$hash = isset($_SESSION['hash']) ? $_SESSION['hash'] : false;` Then you can do `if($hash){ if($password_verify($password, $hash){`...etc

Comment: i tried this. I made a form, where i had to type in a pw. I saved it in a DB. Now i tried to match the input with the hash in the database. it looks like this:    `$sql = "SELECT * from user WHERE email = '$email'";
  $res = mysqli_query($link,$sql);

    $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
  $hash = $user['password'];
  if(password_verify($password, $hash)) echo 'logged in'; else echo 'not found'; '