# Session variable not set at first try

Tags: php

I am using a session variable to check if the user is logged in. But the first time you submit the login form the session variable is somehow unset, but **ONLY** the first time.

If I submit the login form twice it works.

Or let's say I have submitted the form twice in order to log in. Then log out. Now I only need to submit the form once to log in.

Here is the code im using to log in the user:

```js
<?php
session_start();
define('DB_NAME', 'madsanker_dk_db');
define('DB_USER', 'madsanker_dk');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', 'mysql43.unoeuro.com');

$link = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link) {
 die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_error());
}

$db_selected = mysqli_select_db( $link, DB_NAME);

if (!$db_selected) {
 die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_connect_error());
}

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$username = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$username);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link,$password);
$password = md5($password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mainLogin WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);

$count=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  if($count==1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    if ($password == $row['password']){
SETTING THE VARIABLE HERE --> $_SESSION['login'] = $username;
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://www.madsanker.dk'); </script>";
        return true;
    }
    else {
        echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://www.madsanker.dk/loginpage'); </script>";
        return false;
    }
}else{
    echo "<script> window.location.assign('http://www.madsanker.dk/loginpage'); </script>";
    return false;
}
mysqli_close($link);
?>
```

I am sure that the variable is being set the first time, because if I echo the variable and do `exit();` right after it has been set it show up correctly.

The page I am redirecting to looks like this:

```html
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['activePage'] = "home";
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Madsanker</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" name="pageStyle" type="text/css">
        <?php include "nav-bar.php"; ?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Welcome to Madsanker.dk</h2>
        <?php include "chatIframe.php" ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Even if I put `var_dump($_SESSION['login']); exit();` at the top of the document it says `NULL` the first, and the second time it displays the username correctly.

I have been trying to fix this for about an hour now and I really can see why this is not working.

Comment: `md5` is not a secure way to hash your passwords. Consider switching to [password_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right)

Comment: try to use php `header` function to redirect instead of js `window.location.assign` when user is logged in and see the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if you are accessing the first time to your site without **www.** because the second time your are redirecting to **www.madsanker.dk** so the are two different domains.

Hope that helps :D

Comment: Yep thats it. Thank you. Will mark this as correct as soon as it lets me.