# Convert PHP's password_verify to Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

We're in the process of converting our site from an old PHP framework to Rails, and would really like for users to continue being able to login with their old password. On the old site, we're using password_hash and password_verify to hash and verify the passwords. However, on Rails I can't seem to get it to verify the old password.

Here is what we have in PHP:

Hash:

```
password_hash($user['salt'] . $password . $user['salt'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Verify:

```
password_verify($user['salt'] . $password . $user['salt'], $user['password'])
```

On the new Rails framework we're using Devise and have built a custom migration script to move everything over and identify the correct password hashing method based on a password_version stored in the db, and this is what I'm using inside my User model:

```
def valid_password?(password)
  if password_version == 'legacy'
    hash = BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password)
    hash_str = password_salt+password+password_salt

    return hash.is_password? hash_str
  end

  super(password)
end
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: password_verify isn't very complicated. pass in the new pw and original pw hash. yank the crypt method + salt out of the hash, use those to re-hash the new pw, then compare resulting hash values.

Comment: @Script47 Yep, it's supposed to be there.

Comment: @MarcB Yep, that's essentially what I'm trying to do. It *should* be using bcrypt from what I understand of it, so the rails portion should work, I would have thought

Comment: `password_hash` is supposed to work without needing a salt. Adding one just messes things up. Why are you doing that?

Comment: [Please don't add your own salt to password_hash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-verify-function-am-i-doing-it-right). Let it add its own. You will get the salt stored in the hash

Comment: @Machavity Totally agreed, but it looks like the damage is done here.

Comment: @Machavity Yes, I'm aware. I didn't make the current site, just trying to convert it, that provides nothing towards my solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of a PHP `password_hash` password looks roughly like this:

```
$2y$10$.vGA1O9wmRjrwAVXD98HNOgsNpDczlqm3Jq7KnEd1rVAGv3Fykk1a
```

The default Ruby Bcrypt method produces passwords of the form:

```
$2a$10$GtKs1Kbsig8ULHZzO1h2TetZfhO4Fmlxphp8bVKnUlZCBYYClPohG
```

For a clean solution here you can always differentiate between the two by the `$2y` or `$2a` prefix. There's no need for a format column when it's already baked into the format.

For example:

```
case (encrypted_password[0,3])
when '$2y'
  # Legacy PHP password
  BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password.sub(/\A\$2y/, '$2a')).is_password?(salt + password + salt)
when '$2a'
  # Ruby BCrypt password
  BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_password).is_password?(password) 
else
  # Unexpected type?
end
```

What you'll want to do on a successful verification of password is re-write the password to the database using Ruby's method to gradually replace all the old PHP formatted ones.

Comment: Yep, as I said in the question, I already know which passwords are which, it's just a matter of (in ruby) verifying the password with the PHP hash. I'm wanting to keep the password_version as there is an even older legacy password version being used as the current site didn't replace these with the new format, it just allowed them to continue working. I've gotten that one working fine as it was just a hash with a salt

Comment: I'm saying it *should* replace them with the new version. Do you have some test data here that can be used to illustrate the desired output?

Comment: It's going to replace them, the old version didn't so I'm converting two older password hashing methods to the new one using BCrypt

Comment: @jakeb I've updated the answer with some example code. Your `valid_password?` method will need to take both the supplied password and your legacy `salt` value.

Comment: Yep! That did it, thanks. For some reason you mentioning that PHP's starting with $2y didn't even make me think to replace it.

Comment: @jakeb I've had to do something similar to this when dealing with PHP passwords in Python and Node.js before. Glad it worked!