# i created a php form and connects in to mysql my all data is added in database only gender is not showing in the database

Tags: php, mysql

i have created a php form and connected it to mysql successfully, i created a table in mysql and added the data, all data is added except gender is not showing in database instead of gender 0 is displayed in the table.Second probelm is my validation is not working on the form
Below is the code:
Here is the code for database connection and validation:

```
<?php
session_start();
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$mail = $_POST['mail'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$gender = $_POST['gender'];

//database Connection



$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'codetodesign');

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} else {
$stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into registration(firstName, lastName, mail, password, age, gender) 
values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$firstname, $lastname, $mail, $password, $age, $gender);
    $stmt->execute();
echo "Registration successfully";
$stmt->close();
$conn->close();
}

//Validations

$firstnameErr = $lastnameErr = $mailErr = $passwordErr = $ageErr = $genderErr = "";
$firstname = $lastname = $mail = $password = $age = $gender = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
if (empty($_POST["firstname"])){
    $firstnameErr = "Firstname is required";
} else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["lastname"])){
    $lastnameErr = "lastname is required";
} else {
    $lastname = test_input($_POST["lastname"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["mail"])){
    $mailErr = "Mail is required";
} else {
    $mail = test_input($_POST["mail"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["password"])){
    $passwordErr = "Password is required";
} else {
    $password = test_input($_POST["password"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["age"])){
    $ageErr = "Age is required";
} else {
    $age = test_input($_POST["age"]);
}

if (empty($_POST["gender"])){
    $genderErr = "Gender is required";
} else {
    $gender = test_input($_POST["gender"]);
}
}
function test_input($data) {
$data = trim($data);
$data = stripslashes($data);
$data = htmlspecialchars($data);
return $data;
}
?>

Here is the code for gender values:

<div class="form-group">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
        </div>
        <label for="male" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" 
id="male">Male</label>
        <label for="female" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" 
id="female">Female</label>
        <label for="others" class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="o" 
id="other">Other</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Have you try to `var_dump($_POST)` or directly `var_dump($_POST["gender"])` for see if is not empty?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini i made a mistake with query i just replaced that i interger with s and it works thanks for the answer

Comment: is php not jquery :)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini yeah sorry its php

Comment: Apart from trimming, the stuff you do in your `test_input` function is unnecessary since you're using prepared statements. They will automatically sanitize your input values. Furthermore, please see about [password hashing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14992367/using-php-5-5s-password-hash-and-password-verify-function/). Storing plain text passwords is a huge security hole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrong your query, you use "i" with letter.
Change:

```
 $stmt->bind_param("sssssi",$firstname, $lastname, $mail, $password, $age, $gender);
```

into:

```
 $stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$firstname, $lastname, $mail, $password, $age, $gender);
```

Reference for see all type specification chars : [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)

Comment: thanks mate your answer worked for me i made a mistake with query i just replaced that i interger with s and it works

Answer (score -1):

You may set your datatype of gender in mysql database to integer in mysql table. Please check that.
try with this for validation

```
     if (isset($_POST["firstname"])){
if(($_POST["firstname"]="")){
    $firstnameErr = "Firstname is required";
} else {
    $firstname = test_input($_POST["firstname"]);
}
}
```

tips :
please insert your password using md5() function for secuity

Comment: i tried this code but same results when i leave the first name place empty in the form no message is shown to enter the name mean validation is not working. Is there any other way to solve it

Comment: Please don't recommend `md5` for password hashing. The [documentation itself](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.md5) is advising against it as it was built for speed, not safety. The proper things to use would be [`password_hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash) and [`password_verify`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify).